# Having trouble with makefiles on iseries

Tags: gnu-make, gnu, ibm-midrange

Was attempting to use gmake for compiling programs in a logical order to reduce problems and errors. Came accross a website that actually shows this quite well step by step, but upon trying to follow i continually get makefile errors (almost always the missing operator error.) So decided to try the absolute most basic thing possible and work my way up
i simply made a makefile of
hello:
echo "hello world"
Even this however, will not run. I get an error of makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.
I've checked using cat -e -t -v Makefile the format of the file and there are no hidden characters and only tabs (no spaces).
Im using the latest version of gmake for iseries which i installed using YUM and Im running it in a terminal environment after first setting my path using PATH=/QOpenSys/pkgs/bin:$PATH

Please help as this is driving me batty!
Thank you

Comment: Try harder to format your question. Try even simpler `echo hello`.

Comment: sorry Andreas, Im not great at formatting questions :)
Yeah, I had tried that to make sure it wasnt something to do with spaces, and it never worked, but i did get it working using the answer below..

Answer (score 0):

hi all that see this..

Well, i got it resolved (even if i dont quite understand why), I was writing this file using my pspad and visual studio code editors (tried both) and it wouldnt work, I suspected it might be something to do with codepage so just for fun I switched to notepadd++ which gives you an easy option to make it utf-8, wrote it there, and saved. when i executed, it ran first time.. and ive since tried writing more complicated lines and its still working 100%. However (and this is baffling), when i look at the object details on the iseries, the ones that didnt work, AND this one thats working are all showing as code page 1252, so I have no idea why it's working!

Comment: We had a similar issue in the past. And in my experience it has always somrthing to do with the codepage. Eventually a tab in 1252 is not a tab in 1208. We resolved it using 923 for every streamfile. if you have similar issues in the future you can always do a 
```CHGATR OBJ('yourPath') ATR(*CCSID) VALUE(yourCcsid) SUBTREE(*ALL)```